# How can I pass a `sed` command to `popen` without using a raw string?

Tags: python, sed, popen

How can I pass a `sed` command to `popen` without using a raw string?

When I pass an sed command to `popen` in the list form I get an error: `unterminated address regex` (see first example)

```python
>>> COMMAND = ['sed', '-i', '-e', "\$amystring", '/home/map/myfile']
>>> subprocess.Popen(COMMAND).communicate(input=None)
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated address regex
```

using the raw string form it works as expected:

```python
>>> COMMAND = r"""sed -i -e "\$amystring" /home/map/myfile"""
>>> subprocess.Popen(COMMAND, shell=True).communicate(input=None)
```

I'm really interested in passing `"\$amystring"` as an element of the list. Please avoid answers like

```python
>>> COMMAND = r" ".join(['sed', '-i', '-e', "\$amystring", '/home/map/myfile'] 
>>> subprocess.Popen(COMMAND, shell=True).communicate(input=None)
```

Comment: but it shows (None, none) for me.

Comment: What is wrong with `command = 'sed -i -e "\$amystring" /home/map/myfile'`

Comment: The real question is, why are you shelling-out to sed when you're using Python? Have you looked at the re module?

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?s)$', r'\n$amystring', string)`

Comment: It is still a valid question even if there are alternate ways to do in python.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: There are of course alternative ways to do it (python or even directly use of bash). Nonetheless we have sound reasons why we are doing it that way. For your information: we use python to scripts and some parts of our scripts need to substitute user identity (aka su). We try to do our best using subprocess for those parts. For this question I cleaned the context to make a precise question. Any hint to a more pythonic way to use several different user identities in a python script is course welcome,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two forms is that with `shell=True` as an argument, the string gets passed as is to the shell, which then interprets it. This results in (with bash):

```
sed -i -e \$amystring /home/map/myfile
```

being run.

With the list args and the default `shell=False`, python calls the executable directly with the arguments in the list. In this case, the literal string is passed to sed,

```
sed -i -e '\$amystring' /home/map/myfile
```

and `'\$amystring'` is not a valid `sed` expression. In this case, you'd need to call

```
>>> COMMAND = ['sed', '-i', '-e', "$amystring", '/home/map/myfile']
>>> subprocess.Popen(COMMAND).communicate(input=None)
```

since the string does not need to be escaped for the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Indeed I did not realize/see that $ does not need to be scaped.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing as a raw string. There are only raw string *literals*.

A literal -- it is something that you type in the Python source code.

`r'\$amystring'` and `'\\$amystring'` are the same *strings objects* despite being represented using different string *string literals*.

As [@Jonathan Villemaire-Krajden said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460565/4279): if there is no `shell=True` then you don't need to escape `$` shell metacharacter. You only need it if you run the command in the shell:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv)' "\$amystring"
['-c', '$amystring']
```

Note: there is no backslash in the output.

Don't use `.communicate()` unless you redirect standard streams using `PIPE`, you could use `call()`, `check_call()` instead:

```
import subprocess

rc = subprocess.call(['sed', '-i', '-e', '$amystring', '/home/map/myfile'])
```

To emulate the `$amystring` sed command in Python (± newlines):

```
with open('/home/map/myfile', 'a') as file:
    print('mystring', file=file)
```